# Import is not satisfied inside UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, mef

I am using MEF and specificaly IEventAggregator with my project to send signals between my classes, however my Import on IEventAggregator is not satisfied and the value remains NULL ? 
Am I missing something ? Can you Import from MEF inside UserControls ?

```
    public partial class MyControl : UserControl 
    {
        public MyControl()
        {
           InitializeComponent();  
        }

        [Import]
        public IEventAggregator EventAggregator { get; set; }

        public void SomeMethod()
        {
           EventAggregator.GetEvent<ErrorMessage>.Subscribe(SomeOtherMethod);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare imports on a `UserControl`, but something has to satisfy those imports. If WPF is creating your `UserControl` (such as through a `DataTemplate`) then your imports won't be resolved because WPF does not have any intrinsic support for MEF. What you need to do is either obtain your `MyControl` instance via your `CompositionContainer`, or call [`SatisfyImportsOnce`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd779466.aspx) on your `UserControl` once it has been created.

Comment: CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this);